# .htaccess disallow post.php?id=1 (MOD_REWRITE URL's)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just implemented friendly URLS into my CMS and im wondering what would be the best way of stopping users seeing the post when they go to post.php?id=1

EG user visits website and goes to http://domain.com/post.php?id=1 and see's a 404 but when they goto http://domain.com/post/this-is-a-post they see the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite as

```
RewriteRule ^post/this-is-a-post/?$ post.php?id=1
```

But the above code is not a dynamic URL overwrite. You have to specify an ID in your new URL to make it a dynamic call. Like

```
RewriteRule ^post/this-is-a-post/(.+)/?$ post.php?id=$1
```